# discrepancies in the values of a pointer dereference in c

Tags: pointers, reference, dereference

```
char a = 'x';
char *b = &a;
char *c = &b;


printf("%p\n", c);   //outputs 0060FF04
printf("%p\n", &b);  //outputs 0060FF04
printf("%p\n", *c);  //outputs 0000000B
printf("%p\n", *&b); //outputs 0060FF0B
printf("%p\n", &a);  //outputs 0060FF0B
```

So basically, the concept of pointers is new to me and was running some tests to understand it better. Anyway as you can see, the 1st and the 2nd output is similar as I expected. however, dereferencing char c outputs 0000000B instead the memory address of a which is 0060FF0B.
So my question is if `c = &b` then how come `*c != *&b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `c` should be `char **`, not `char *`. The program interprets 0x0060FF0B as a 1-byte char, giving 0x0B.

Comment: This answer is correct.  `c` is a pointer, but `*c` is a char -- an 8-bit value on most systems.  `&b` is a pointer.  Therefore, `*c` is narrower and can't possibly hold all the possible values of `&b`